# How to add multiple classes for ul element

Tags: html, html-lists

How do I add another ul class to this line:

```
 <ul class="sub-menu">
```

I tried to do like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu"."insert">
```

But it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, classes are separated by space. So,

```
<ul class="sub-menu insert">
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes in HTML are space separated. so just write:

```
<ul class="sub-menu insert">
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have a dot between classes.

It will go like

```
<ul class="sub-menu insert">
```

just a space between the classes/